# matplotlib issue with polar plot after 2.0.2

Tags: python, matplotlib

Releases of matplotlib after 2.0.2 cause the polar plot to be drawn incorrectly. The top of the green plot goes missing. None of the input data has been changed between versions.

**Version 2.1.0**

[image: Version 2.1.0]

**Version 2.0.2 (good)**

[image: Version 2.0.2 (good)]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

theta_radians = np.radians(theta)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, polar=True)
ax.set_theta_zero_location("S")
ax.plot(theta_radians, r, color='green')
ax.plot(np.dot(theta_radians, -1), r, color='green')
ax.plot(horiz, arr[25, :])
fig.savefig('./filename.png', dpi=300)
fig.show()
```

Comment: can you share the data?

Comment: Thanks for the interest GlobalTraveler. I worked out the issue, just needed to set limits, apparently 0 is not necessarily the default. The data is from lighting tests IESNA:LM-63-2002.

Comment: Right that what I was thinking too. Glad you figured it out. Just out of curiosity did you test this on 3.x?

Comment: I tested this on every minor release from 2.0.2 (known good) to 3.0.2 (latest).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be in the way it sets the bottom limit. I managed to resolve this using:

```
ax.set_rlim(0,max)
```

[Fixed Example Version 3.0.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kp7v6.png)

Comment: Because it's not clear what `max` is, maybe you mean `ax.set_rlim(0,None)`?

Comment: Good idea. If i `set_rticks` it will display correctly using `ax.set_rlim(0, None)` otherwise the scale is off (max is 1.0). This is due to `set_rlim` having `auto=False` by default - it doesn't attempt to scale. If i enable `auto=True` this leads to the same conditions as the original post, even if i set r_ticks. 
[Relevant library code](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/61dec521155728c604761e389f769a7409a19303/lib/matplotlib/projections/polar.py#L1170)

Comment: Thank you for fixing the images in my question. I did't have enough reputation yet.